# A monitor concern

Tags: display

So I just bought a new monitor and I really like it, but when I turn it on it just stays black. I have to hold a Hz button at the bottom of the monitor for it to turn on or at least display the picture. Is that normal or should I be concerned?

Comment: Look in its documentation for native resolution. It seems like it is not native for your computer. If true, a call to the monitor manufacturer Support people may have a suggestion for you.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned, but that is indeed trying to indicate a setting is likely not correctly set. This info may help us: 1)provide the monitor brand, model, & P/N. 2)The type of connection is uses (VGA [blue square], DVI [white square], HDMI, DisplayPort). 3)The operating system you use (ex: Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the refresh rate frequency (Hz) or resolution your PC is outputting:

1. Display Settings
2. Advanced display settings

   a.  Change resolution to whatever is needed here based on what your monitor can support. Skip this if you're not sure, but you may need to consults its manual
3. Display adapter properties
4. Monitor (tab)
5. Screen refresh rate is usually 60Hz